# Relative links on local setup not workin

Tags: 6, navigation

Im currently working through some problems putting a drupal 6 site I inherited onto my local machine for testing and development purposes. My server environment is IIS7.5 and I am working with a drupal 6 installation

The latest problem I have relates to some (but not all) links on the site

on my local site my links are resolving to a URL www.example.com/ whereas I want them to resolve to localhost:456
but on my live site those same links seem to be relative as when I type in the IP address of the server all the links in the site look like 159.xx.xxx.xx/page-title and if I put in the URL they all look like example.com/page-title

~I have set teh base_url in settings .php to localhost:456 in my local set up.

I cant understand how they are relative on the live site but seem to be hardcoded on the local site?

the links are being created like so:

```
l(t('Trading Platforms'), 'product', $menulnk_class);
```

all help greatly appreciated

Comment: you have the base_url set to localhost/456, or localhost:456?

Comment: sorry my mistake.. its http://localhost:456  changing the main text now to reflect that